# want SSH banner to show up before OTP and password request

Tags: ssh, banner, two-factor-authentication

We use two-factor-authentication for some servers, i.e. OTP (one time password) token plus password.

I want to provide users with some informations BEFORE they are asked for their credentials. With single factor authentication this can easily be done with the usual banner, e.g. as a file like /etc/ssh/sshd_banner with the according text, and in /etc/ssh/sshd_config with something like

`Banner /etc/ssh/sshd_banner`

Unfortunately it does not seem to work with 2FA. The banner & config are in place, but the login procedure looks like this:

```
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.

Your OTP: ******

Using keyboard-interactive authentication.

Password: **********
```

here comes the banner text, too late:

```
Login on this host as <x-userid> & OTP, proceed to your hosts as <userid>

Last login: Wed Mar 29 11:48:34 2017 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
x-xyz@host:~>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try putting the banner in `/etc/issue.net`?
This should displayed before anything else.